# Pylons and WebHelpers: url() method

Tags: python, pylons

Following [Pylons sample code](http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pylons-webframework/en/latest/forms.html) regarding the "helpers", there's the following snippet:

```
${h.form(h.url(action='email'), method='get')}
Email Address: ${h.text('email')}
${h.submit('Submit')}
${h.end_form()}
```

However, apparently, there's no `url` method in WebHelpers as the server throws `AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'url'`.

Am I doing something wrong?  If no, what is the equivalent of `url()`?

Answer (score 0):

Somehow obscure for someone new to Pylons.  It should have been mentioned in the docs, IMHO.

The answer to "[Mocking away the url object in Pylons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4275389/mocking-away-the-url-object-in-pylons)", has my answer.  I need `from pylons import url` in `helpers.py`.